# Magestore's Web POS extension seems broken

Tags: jquery, magento

For anyone who is familiar with the Web POS extension to Magento, we recently installed Web POS on our store, but can't add items to the cart. Due to the utter lack of documentation on this extension by Magestore, I'm not even sure where to begin troubleshooting the problem.

I've poked around enough to figure out that it seems to be a problem with the javascript they are loading (or perhaps more specifically the order in which they are loading it).

I realize this is a somewhat vague question, but I'm hoping someone with Magento or possibly Web POS experience can help me begin.

For starters...
the ajax functionality on the page seems to be working fine, but when we click an item from the ajax search results in order to add it to the cart, nothing happens.

- On page load, we get the following javascript errors:

  - Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function 11b8f612c13dd60724d5da1b2b0d5c58.js:14176
  - Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined (index):87 Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'updateJscartEvent'
- After clicking the item to add to cart, we get the following javscript error:

  - Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'addToCartHandle'

Answer (score 0):

I'm Justin - Technical supporter from www.magestore.com. 
We are so sorry about your problem. Your problem might be caused due to Merge JavaScript Files feature before installing Web POS module. Now, I suggest 2 solutions for this problem.

Solution 1:

- Go to your back-end->System->Configuration->Developer->JavaScript Settings and select Merge JavaScript Files as No. After that, you need to go to System->Cache Management and click the Flush JavaScript/CSS Cache button. Finally, you can enable Merge JavaScript Files feature and check it again.

Solution 2:

- You need to make this solution if the solution 1 doesn't work for you.
- Firstly: you need to open the file: app/code/local/Magestore/Webpos/etc/config.xml and add the code under global tag/blocks tag as below:

> ```
> <page>
>     <rewrite><html_head>Magestore_Webpos_Block_Html_Head</html_head>
>       </rewrite>
> </page>
> ```

- Secondly, you create a new file: app/code/local/Magestore/Webpos/Block/Html/Head.php with content as below:

> ```
> <?php
>
> class Magestore_Webpos_Block_Html_Head extends Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head
> {
>   protected function &_prepareStaticAndSkinElements($format, array $staticItems, array $skinItems, $mergeCallback = null)
>     {
>       if(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getModuleName()=='webpos'){
>            $mergeCallback = null;
>       }
>         $designPackage = Mage::getDesign();
>         $baseJsUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl('js');
>         $items = array();
>         if ($mergeCallback && !is_callable($mergeCallback)) {
>             $mergeCallback = null;
>         }
>
>         // get static files from the js folder, no need in lookups
>         foreach ($staticItems as $params => $rows) {
>             foreach ($rows as $name) {
>                 $items[$params][] = $mergeCallback ? Mage::getBaseDir() . DS . 'js' . DS . $name : $baseJsUrl . $name;
>             }
>         }
>
>         // lookup each file basing on current theme configuration
>         foreach ($skinItems as $params => $rows) {
>             foreach ($rows as $name) {
>                 $items[$params][] = $mergeCallback ? $designPackage->getFilename($name, array('_type' => 'skin'))
>                     : $designPackage->getSkinUrl($name, array());
>             }
>         }
>
>         $html = '';
>         foreach ($items as $params => $rows) {
>             // attempt to merge
>             $mergedUrl = false;
>             if ($mergeCallback) {
>                 $mergedUrl = call_user_func($mergeCallback, $rows);
>             }
>             // render elements
>             $params = trim($params);
>             $params = $params ? ' ' . $params : '';
>             if ($mergedUrl) {
>                 $html .= sprintf($format, $mergedUrl, $params);
>             } else {
>                 foreach ($rows as $src) {
>                     $html .= sprintf($format, $src, $params);
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>         return $html;
>     }
>
> }
> ```

- Finally, please clear cache on your site and check it again.

If errors still occur, you can contact me at support@magestore.com or submit a ticket to http://support.magestore.com. I will reply within 24 hours.

Hope you succeed.

Justin

Comment: We ended up abandoning the magestore pos. We got rid of a bunch of the javascript it was caching to get it to function, but every time we had to refresh the cache we had to go edit the cached javascript file.